# After svelte init - App.svelte won't show up

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

Dumb question incoming: Where is App.svelte? I initialized a project skeleton with `npm create svelte@latest myapp`, cd into it, do `npm install` and `npm run dev`, but App.svelte won't appear. There is an app.html in the src/ directory, but telling from the .html suffix I cannot do the cool svelte-stuff with it. There must be an App.svelte file somewhere. I can create it manually, but then, how to I tell the bundler to make it the new index.html? I'm confused.

Thanks in advance.

I checked the docs and did some trial-and-error, without any result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`app.html` is like the shell for the svelte components. Inside `app.html` the `%sveltekit.body%` tag is replaced with a route. The index route is `src/routes/+page.svelte`. SvelteKit is a filesystem-based router. The [docs page](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/project-structure) is very good and almost contains all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that some older documentations refer to the `App.svelte` file. I believe this might be deprecated. I couldn't find any information to confirm this though. You can use `routes/+layout.svelte` to write what you wanted to write in `App.svelte`.